# How to use "hierarchical path" of chisel/scala?

Tags: scala, chisel

In verilog there is such a way to access other module's stuff, as I know it was called "hierarchical path", here is a verilog RTL

```
module A;
  reg a;
endmodule
module tb;
  A u_A();
  wire b;
  assign b = u_A.a; // hierarchical path
endmodule
```

Could you enlight me how to access Reg/Wire of other Modules in Chisel/Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible in chisel3.  If you try you will get an error

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Connection between sink (chisel3.core.UInt@b) and source (chisel3.core.UInt@1b) failed @: Source is unreadable from current module. 
chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Connection between sink (chisel3.core.UInt@b) and source (chisel3.core.UInt@1b) failed @: Source is unreadable from current module
```

If you want to expose it to outside modules you should do that through the io mechanism.
That being said it is possible to create the syntactic appearance of direct access to the module by using the experimental feature MultiIOModule

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.experimental._

class A extends MultiIOModule {
  val reg = Reg(UInt(16.W))
  val r = IO(Output(reg))
  r := reg
}

class B extends MultiIOModule {
  val u_A = Module(new A)
  val b = Wire(UInt(16.W))
  b := u_A.r
}
```